# Jena Sparql Query on Endpoint

Tags: java, json, sparql, jena, wikidata

This is my simple query. It works if i set the limit to 60k.
I think it's a problem of some strange characters in the json.

```sql
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?itemLabel 
WHERE {
  ?id ?label "person"@en.
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?id.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
  bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
  }
}
```

This is my java code.

```java
Query q = QueryFactory.create(query.getQuery());

QueryEngineHTTP qexec =new QueryEngineHTTP("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql", query.getQuery());
qexec.addParam("format", "json");
qexec.setModelContentType(WebContent.contentTypeJSONLD);
        try {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        qexec.close();
```

and finally this is my Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.atlas.json.JsonParseException: Not a colon: [KEYWORD:person]
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONParserBase.exception(JSONParserBase.java:132)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseObject(JSONP.java:74)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseAny(JSONP.java:97)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseObject(JSONP.java:79)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseAny(JSONP.java:97)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseArray(JSONP.java:146)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseAny(JSONP.java:98)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseObject(JSONP.java:79)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseAny(JSONP.java:97)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parseObject(JSONP.java:79)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONP.parse(JSONP.java:50)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:58)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.io.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:40)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.JSON._parse(JSON.java:140)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.json.JSON.parse(JSON.java:37)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.resultset.JSONInput.parse(JSONInput.java:113)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.resultset.JSONInput.process(JSONInput.java:100)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.resultset.JSONInput.fromJSON(JSONInput.java:63)
    at org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFactory.fromJSON(ResultSetFactory.java:331)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:385)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:351)
    at core.ExecuteQuery.<init>(ExecuteQuery.java:40)
    at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

I would skip the problem in order to obtain

Comment: The problem is in the results somewhere.   Try make the query call with curl or wegt to get the actual bytes sent back. Also, have you tried other formats?

Comment: Other issue: `setModelContentType(WebContent.contentTypeJSONLD);`  This only applies to CONSTRUCT and DESCRIBE.

Comment: A an aside, please don't use the "stack snippets" for code that can't run in a browser.  Just use normal code blocks for those.

Comment: First of all thank you for the help. 
The malformed result cames from a set of strings at the end of the file: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bigdata.bop.engine.QueryTimeoutException: Query deadline is expired etc that obviously corrupt the Json file.